# I am trying to set all rigidbodys' velocity to 0, then to what it was before

Tags: velocity, godot, gdscript

So I have been trying to create a pause menu for the past few hours. However, I cannot figure out how to stop the rigidbodies from moving. If there is a way to stop all rigidbodies at once, please tell me, if not, I can set it to each and every script with a rigid body. Here is my code so far:

```
extends Position3D
onready var charCamera = get_viewport().get_camera()
##var direction = Camera.global_transform.basis.get_euler()

signal spawned(spawn)

export(PackedScene) var spawnling_scene
var linear_velocity_on_pause = 0
var not_paused_anymore = false
var paused = false
#var Popup1 = self.get_parent().get_parent().get_parent().get_node("Popup")
func _physics_process(_delta):
    
    if self.get_parent().get_parent().get_parent().get_node("Popup").visible == false:
        if Input.is_action_pressed("leftClick"):
            spawn()
        if paused == true:
            not_paused_anymore = true
            paused = false
        
    if self.get_parent().get_parent().get_parent().get_node("Popup").visible == true:
        linear_velocity_on_pause = spawnling_scene.instance().linear_velocity
        paused = true
        spawnling_scene.instance().set_mode(1)
        spawnling_scene.instance().linear_velocity = get_parent().get_parent().get_parent().get_node("LinearVelocityOf0").linear_velocity
    
    if not_paused_anymore == true:
        spawnling_scene.instance().set_mode(0)
        
        spawnling_scene.instance().linear_velocity = linear_velocity_on_pause
        not_paused_anymore = false

func spawn():
    var spawnling = spawnling_scene.instance()
    spawnling.linear_velocity = charCamera.global_transform.basis.z * -100
    #spawnling.global_transform.basis = charCamera.global_transform.basis
    add_child(spawnling)
    spawnling.set_as_toplevel(true)
    emit_signal("spawned", spawnling)
    ##insert pause system
    return spawnling

##var spawnling = spawnling_scene.instance()
##  
##  add_child(spawnling)
##  spawnling.set_as_toplevel(true)
```

Answer (score 2):

*I'm not answering the question of how to set the velocity of all rigid bodies to zero.*

---

If you want to make a pause menu, this is what you should know:

Godot has a puse system, which you can use like this to pause:

```
get_tree().paused = true
```

And to resume:

```
get_tree().paused = false
```

See [Pausing Games](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/pausing_games.html).

Which `Node`s gets to execute when `get_tree().paused` is set to `true` depend on their `pause_mode` property. By default they will all stop, but if you set their `pause_mode` to `PAUSE_MODE_PROCESS` they will continue to work when `get_tree().paused` is set to `true`. And that is what you want to do with the `Node` that make up your pause menu UI.

---

However, that system will not pause shaders. Their `TIME` will continue to tick. If you want to "freeze" shaders you can set a 0 to their time scaling like this:

```
VisualServer.set_shader_time_scale(0)
```

Set it to `1` for normal speed:

```
VisualServer.set_shader_time_scale(0)
```

And you can set other values to have them slow down or speed up.

---

Speaking of slow down and speed up. If you want to do that for the rest of the game (not just shaders), you can use `Engine.time_scale`. And if there is some timing that you don't want to be affected, you would have to write it using the time functions in the `OS` class.